# Electron - is there a performance overhead to relaying IPC calls?

Tags: javascript, electron

I was wondering if there's a  performance overhead to IPC calls Is there a measurable difference in performance when a user action requires sending just one message vs. a chain of 3 messages?

I plan to structure my app like this:

- Main Process
- API Renderer - contains the API
- UI Renderer - contains UI

So the communication between UI and API looks like this:

`UI Renderer -> Main Process (relay) -> API Renderer`

(as it's not possible to send messages between renderers directly)

In some scenarios where the API requires something from the main process it can even be like:

`UI Renderer -> Main Process (relay) -> API Renderer -> Main Process`

Could having so many IPC calls negatively affect the performance of the app?

For instance, I could consider to implement the API in the main process, so it would be simply:

`UI Renderer -> Main Process (API)`

without any relays, and if the API needs something from Node, it's already there.

However, I want to split the API from the main process to enhance security. In case I would want to offer the possibility of third party extensions in the future, I want to have the API process run in a renderer with nodeIntegration disabled.

Should I be concerned about performance here?

(By the way, if you are wondering why I split API and UI into different processes, I have to, because I need to run the UI in multiple separate processes, so there's one API and multiple UIs that are using the API.)

Comment: For less than 10K messages per second I bet you could hardly tell.

Comment: Rule of thumb: Unless you have a *measurable* performance problem, don't worry about it.

Comment: "premature optimization". . . is a heartbreaking problem. 